# how to install apc for php on mac osx mamp?

Tags: php, mamp, apc

I am running a mac with mamp and mamp pro. How do I check if I have APC enabled and if its not enabled or not installed how do I install it?

I am trying to get the APC upload loader to work that I found online and it gets stuck on NAN% when im uploading.

This is a link: http://www.haughin.com/2007/10/23/php-upload-progress-with-php-52-apc/

Answer (score 24):

There's nothing to download or install. MAMP 1.9 includes APC already. To enable it, open Preferences/PHP. Uncheck 'Zend Optimizer' (because it's not compatible with APC), then choose APC from the 'Cache' drop-down box, submit the change with 'OK'.

Comment: and 4 years later this still works. I don't see Zend optimizer but you can go to Preferences -> PHP -> Cache -> APC and it works all fine :)

Answer (score 17):

In MAMP 2.1 you can find the APC setting in the Main Window under Server > PHP > Cache:

[image]

In MAMP 3.0 APC is found on the PHP tab:

[image]

Comment: What if you use MAMP and not MAMP Pro?

Comment: According to the officialy MAMP website, the APC Cache is available in both MAMP and MAMP Pro versions: http://www.mamp.info/en/mamp-pro/features/matrix.html

Comment: MAMP 3.0 solution above is also the same for v3.3 and v3.4

Comment: Worth noting that APC is currently not compatible with PHP version 7.0, so the APC option will be greyed out if you have PHP 7.0 selected.

Answer (score 2):

For command-line support add also the following lines to your MAMP php.ini:

`[apc]
    extension=apcu.so
    apc.enable_cli=1`

Answer (score 0):

Visit the phpinfo page that you can get to from inside the MAMP start page. That lists all of the loaded modules.

Here are the install steps for PHP-APC:

[link text](http://www.php.net/manual/en/apc.installation.php)

You may be able to run `pear` or `pecl` inside MAMP to do the install easily.

Comment: I am having the same issue, I was able to install APC using `pecl install APC` After installation I was able to grab the apc.so file: `/opt/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/apc.so` and replace the `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/apc.so` file. I think im on the right track, but when rebooting apache it no longer says apc is installed when using `phpinfo()`

Answer (score 0):

Do it manually:

1- `nano /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.2/conf/php.ini`

> NOTE: "**php5.6.2**" on the path should be changed to the php version
>   you'll be using.

2- Look for the section:

`[OPcache]
;zend_extension="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.2/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/opcache.so"`

3- Remove the colon (;) so that section reads:

`[OPcache]
zend_extension="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.2/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/opcache.so"`

4- Save `(Ctrl-O) + Enter` and quit `(Ctrl-X)`

Enjoy.

> When running PHP scripts from the Console (CLI) you will need to
>   specify the PHP binary you want to use since by default php will be
>   the default PHP included with OS X, not the one installed with MAMP.
>
> So instead of:
>
> ```
> user$ php script.php
> ```
>
> try:
>
> ```
> user$ /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.2/bin/php script.php
> ```